# After getting table results Want to display same as in the UI side as like image attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, webmethod

SELECT left([Action],CHARINDEX(':',[Action])-1)As Heading,RIGHT([Action],LEN([Action])-CHARINDEX(':',[Action])-1)as Category, Currency, UnitRate, UnitOfMeasure, ChargeAmount, Quantity,istotal_indicator
        FROM (
         SELECT AttributeName
          ,attributevalue , [Action] ,t2.istotal_indicator
         from tbl_ss_orderitems_IC t1 join 
       Tbl_ECC_breakdowns t2

```
    on t1.[Action]= t2.ECC_Charge_Actiontype        
     WHERE AttributeName IN (                                        
       'ChargeAmount'                        
       ,'Currency'                        
       ,'Quantity'                        
       ,'UnitOfMeasure'                        
       ,'UnitRate' 

       )                        
      --AND [Action] like '%::%'  AND workitemid = 'OS01EWDF00Test_1234'      
     ) AS A                        
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(AttributeValue) 
    FOR AttributeName IN (                                       
       ChargeAmount                       
       ,Currency                      
       ,Quantity                       
       ,UnitOfMeasure                      
       ,UnitRate           
       )
     ) AS PIVOT_1
```

After excute the query get Table Results data

[image]

want to Display same like  In UI side using the result table data records

[image]

Answer (score -1):

after execute query you have to store result data in an array then using foreach loop you can show row in table format one by one.